# Merge several columns from multiple csv files to one csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I'm just starting to learning Pandas and I'm currently tring to merge several columns from different csv files to one csv file. Here below is the original files.

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
source_file = pd.read_csv("E:\\bachelor thesismaterials\\TrainData\\CSV\\Forward_2_4\\F358\\CH1.CSV")
column_sensor_1 = 'C1 in V'
column_to_save = source_file[column_sensor_1] 
target_file = pd.DataFrame(data={'':[column_to_save]},dtype = int) 
target_file.to_csv('E:\\bachelor thesis materials\\1d\\Forward_1.csv',index=False)
```

> [original file part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cm5A.png)

> [original file  part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2pvj.png)

> [original file  part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ2Zu.png)

I'm trying to combine column 'C1 in V', 'C2 in V', 'C3 in V' together and the result should looks like [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jCG0.png)

But when I'm using DataFrame, the new input always replace existed data in the file and the format is strange, all data is stored in a single cell.

Could u guys help? Thks a lot.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example of data in code and expected output. Links to private folders and pictures are not very helpful :-)

Comment: Hmph... First of all, a csv file is a **text** file! So instead of giving non copyable images, please show the content as text, as it appears in a simple text editor like notepad, notepad++ of vi. Next, you do not show how you combine the columns so this is not a [mcve]. As a new user, you should read [ask] to know how questions are expected to be asked here.

Comment: Thks a lot. Problem solved. I will read 'How to Ask', thks. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

forward = None
for i in range(3):
    j = i + 1
    t = pd.read_csv(f'E:\\bachelor thesismaterials\\TrainData\\CSV\\Forward_2_4\\F358\\CH{j}.CSV')[f'C{j} in V'].to_frame()
    forward = t if forward is None else forward.join(t)
f = 'E:\\bachelor thesis materials\\1d\\Forward_1.csv'
forward.to_csv(f, index=False)
forward = pd.read_csv(f)
print(forward)
```

Output:

```
    C1 in V   C2 in V  C3 in V
0  0.008496  0.006152 -0.01221
1  0.010059  0.004199 -0.01709
2  0.012793  0.004004 -0.02275
3  0.014746  0.002246 -0.02803
4  0.018262  0.002441 -0.03311
5  0.020801  0.002441 -0.03936
6  0.019043  0.001855 -0.04443
7  0.018457 -0.000490 -0.04775
```

Comment: Thks a lot. That's really helpful！ : )